# Detect Windows Phone 8.1 versus UWPapp on Windows Phone in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am trying to find a way to distinguish if my app is running as UWP app on a phone or if it Both WinPhone 8.1 and UWP app on a phone have a Device.OS of TargetPlatform.Windows.  Thus I cannot find a way to determine if it is a UWP app or Windows Phone 8.1 app running in a phone.  Any suggestions?  My sample code is below.

```
        if ( Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows)
        {
            this.grdButtons.ColumnSpacing = 0;
        }
```

Comment: can you check Device.Idiom to see if it is a phone or a tablet?

Comment: Do you want to detect  device platform ( Windows Rt or Windows 10) or device idiom(phone or tablet)?

Comment: I would like to detect both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 as well as UWP apps on a phone and desktop.  To be clear I need to know if it is a UWP app running - NOT just if it is Windows 10 as Windows Phone 8.1 Apps can run on Windows 10.

Comment: have you found any solution so far ?

Comment: Sorry no - In VS 2017 Win Phone 8.1 projects are no longer available though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer.

Below: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device

The using-directive `Xamarin.Forms` offers a function to get the runtime-platform. You can compare it to Android, WinRT, WinPhone, macOS, iOS, UWP. For example:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform.Equals(Device.UWP))
{

}
```

Furthermore you can also compare the device's idiom, to identify if your application is running on Phone, Tablet, ...

Comment: Thanks - yes this feature was added in a future release of Xamarin after I published my app.  I have used it in updated versions.